# Stream reduce operation using interface

Tags: java, java-stream, reduce

I have the following structure

```
public interface ICommon{
   ICommon add(ICommon other);
}

public class Foo implements ICommon{
    ...

    ICommon add(ICommon other){
        return new Bar().add(other);
    }

}

public class Bar implements ICommon{
    ...

    ICommon add(ICommon other){
        ...
    }

}
```

As part of a composite pattern.

I wanted to use the streams reduce operation, but somehow I can not force the type inference to the interface. I am using this.

```
List<Foo> list;
list.stream().reduce( new Foo(), (a,b) -> a.add(b));
```

I am getting an error that `ICommon` can not be cast to `Foo`.

I have tried to force cast on parameters but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the three-arg version of `reduce` allowing to change the element type when performing the reduction:

```
list.stream().reduce(new Foo(), ICommon::add, ICommon::add);
```

While a reference to the same method is used here, the second argument is a function (`BiFunction`) with an `(ICommon,Foo) -> ICommon` signature, whilst the third argument is a function (`BinaryOperator`) with an `(ICommon,ICommon) -> ICommon` signature.

Another option is to do a type safe change of the existing `List`’s type:

```
Collections.<ICommon>unmodifiableList(list).stream().reduce(new Foo(), ICommon::add);
```

Since immutable lists can guaranty to return values of the super type of the actual element type, while preventing the inserting of new elements, this wrapper allows to change the element type to a super type. Further, since stream operations are read-only operations, the wrapper redirects the `stream()` invocation to the original list, just returning it as a stream of the supertype. So there is no performance difference to using `list.stream()` directly.

Comment: This is actually very helpful. Is there a difference for parallel streams between the two versions of `reduce`?

Comment: No practical difference. For the three-arg version, the implementation will typically use the first function for sequential partial evaluation followed by using the second function for merging these results. Since these functions should be semantically equivalent (here, it’s a reference to the same method), it makes no difference. The two-arg version does exactly the same, just using the provided function for both, sequential partial evaluation and merging. Likely by calling into exactly the same implementation method internally.

Comment: The second option is the first time I see it. I did not even know it is possible (first time I saw the generic type being passed like that). Do you have a reference to `Collections.<ICommon>unmodifiableList(list)`

Comment: This is just an invocation with an explicit type, as shown [in the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html) (compare the two variants at the end). The method itself is just [`Collections.unmodifiableList(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-). It also works with implicit types, e.g. in an assignment: `List<ICommon> newList = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);`

Comment: I always used the implicit assignment. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that your `List` is parametrized with `Foo`, but your reduction operations will be parametrized with `ICommon` due to the `add` invocation.

While all `Foo`s are `ICommon`s, not all `ICommon`s will be `Foo`s.

The easiest way for you would be to parametrize your `List` with `ICommon` instead, without changing anything else in your (visible) code.

Something like:

```
List<ICommon> list = [some list of Foos];
list.stream().reduce( new Foo(), (a,b) -> a.add(b));
```

Comment: The list was parametrized with `Foo` since I was creating a stream of `Foo`. I just listed it as this to provide a minimum example. Thank you. This works.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to the problem. The reduce operation has the signature

```
T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator);
```

All I had to do is cast to a stream of `ICommon`

```
list.stream().map(x-> (ICommon) x).reduce( new Foo(), (a,b) -> a.add(b));
```

Comment: No need to do a cast, `list.stream().reduce(new Foo(), ICommon::add, ICommon::add);`…